# MongoDB - Find is array exists within an object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql

I have a large collection of different products with various fields. 
Once field is named 'ar_related' 
This holds 0 or many different arrays. For example it could hold:

also_viewed, also_bought, bought_together, buy_after_viewing

Here is an example of a document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a95cef390bd8fbf1c699d6d"),
"ar_asin" : "0078764343",
"ar_description" : "Brand new sealed!",
"ar_price" : 37.98,
"ar_imUrl" : "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/513h6dPbwLL._SY300_.jpg",
"ar_related" : {
    "also_bought" : [ 
        "B000TI836G", 
        "B003Q53VZC", 
        "B00EFFW0HC", 
        "B003VWGBC0", 
        "B003O6G5TW", 
        "B0037LTTRO", 
        "B002I098JE", 
        "B008OQTS0U", 
        "B005EVEODY", 
        "B008B3AVNE", 
        "B000PE0HBS", 
        "B00354NAYG", 
        "B0050SYPV2", 
        "B00503E8S2", 
        "B0050SY77E", 
        "B0022TNO7S", 
        "B0056WJA30", 
        "B0023CBY4E", 
        "B002SRSQ72", 
        "B005EZ5GQY", 
        "B004XACA60", 
        "B00273Z9WM", 
        "B004HX1QFY", 
        "B002I0K50U"
    ],
    "bought_together" : [ 
        "B002I098JE"
    ],
    "buy_after_viewing" : [ 
        "B0050SY5BM", 
        "B000TI836G", 
        "B0037LTTRO", 
        "B002I098JE"
    ]
},
"ar_salesRank" : {
    "Video Games" : 28655
},
"ar_categories" : [ 
    [ 
        "Video Games", 
        "Xbox 360", 
        "Games"
    ]
]
}
```

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to return (and count) all products which contain the 'bought_together' array within the ar_related object. Some products contain it and some do not.

I have tried a few different approaches, mostly with the $elemMatch operator but am having no luck. I am new to NoSQL as from a SQL background.

Any response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful research, Ive found this answer.

```
db.P14162135_products.find({
    "ar_related.brought_together":{$exists: true}

}).count();
```

Thank you all for the responses

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('products').find({ "ar_related": {
    $exists: true, 
    $elemMatch: { "bought_together": {$exists: true} } 
}
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I just tried your answer and unfortunately it returned 0 results.

Comment: Sorry my bad. `{$exists: true}` should be true. check updated

Comment: I ran the updated, but i'm afraid the same result, 0 results returned. I made sure the collection name was correct as the collection is named 'P14162135_products'